# Prove that for $f:A \to [0,\infty)$ if $\sum\limits_{a\in\mathbb A} f(a) < \infty$ then $\{a \in A\mid f(a) \neq0\}$ is at most countable.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, fourier-analysis

Prove that for $$f:A \to [0,\infty)$$ if $$\sum\limits_{a\in\mathbb A} f(a) < \infty$$
 then $\{a \in A\mid f(a) \neq0\}$ is at most countable.

I tried but i didn't conclude to anything.Any ideas for prove this?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/372125/462).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider the sets

$$
A_n := \{a \in A \,\mid \, f(a) \geq 1/n \}.
$$

> Each of these sets is finite (why?) and $\{a \in A \, \mid \, f(a) \neq 0\} = ???$.

Comment: i can estimate exactly the {$a \in A/f(a) \neq0$}   ?

Comment: @paris: Not, but you should be able to express $\{a \in A \mid f(a) \neq 0\}$ as a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: beacause all these sets are finite, are countables and the union of {$a \in A/f(a) \neq0$} are all these sets adn that's why is countable?

Comment: @paris: Yes, exactly.

Comment: these sets are finite because $\sum\limits_{a\in\mathbb A} f(a) \lt {\infty}$ ?

Comment: @paris: Yes, if you let $M := \sum_{a \in A} f(a)$, then you can easily show that $\# \{a \in A \mid f(a) \geq 1/n\} \leq nM < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\{f(a) : a\in A\}$. Then consider these sets:
\begin{align}
& B\cap [1,\infty) \\
& B\cap [1/2,1) \\
& B\cap [1/3,1/2) \\
& B\cap [1/4,1/3) \\
& B\cap [1/5,1/4) \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \vdots
\end{align}
See if you can show that if $\displaystyle\sum_{a\in A} f(a) <\infty $ then every one of the sets above must be finite.  And then think about how many sets are in the sequence above.

Comment: how i can show that  $$\sum\limits_{a\in\mathbb A} f(a) \lt {\infty}$$

Comment: @paris : The point of your question seems to be to prove that _if_ that sum is $<\infty$ then something follows.  To do that, you don't need to prove that the sum is $<\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$